# Почему не срабатывает docker команда под MAC?

Tags: macos, docker

Есть команда:

```
docker-compose run --no-deps --rm php-bundle /bin/bash  -c "useradd -u 501 docker && su -c 'phpunit tests' docker"
```

Она отлично работает на linux (ubuntu), однако на OSX, пользователь, который выполняет данную команду попадает в терминал контейнера, и вот эта часть не выполняется:

```
"useradd -u 501 docker && su -c 'phpunit tests' docker"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема ?

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    ...

    php-bundle:
        container_name: travellizy_client_php_bundle
        build: ./docker/php-bundle
        working_dir: /www
        volumes:
            - ./www:/www
        networks:
            travellizy_client:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.110.119

networks:
    travellizy_client:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.110.0/24
                  gateway: 192.168.110.1
```

Comment: какая ошибка? что в **docker-compose.yml**?

Comment: Ошибки нет. Тоесть на Linux все отрабатывает, а на OSX пользователь просто попадает в консоль контейнера и команда "useradd -u 501 docker && su -c 'phpunit tests' docker" не отрабатывает.

Comment: какой docker установлен?

Comment: Linux: Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
------------
OSX: Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

Comment: так **docker-compose.yml** добавите?

Comment: http://ideone.com/B5LAZD

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: оно не влазит и не форматирует

Comment: все отлично форматируется. Используйте отступ в 4 пробела. Уберите лишнее и оставьте только нужное.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61760/discussion-between-nepster-and-mikhail-vaysman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем такое поведение наблюдалось только на конкретном устройстве и после переустановки докера с полным ресетом проблема ушла.